# Using double time $_GET title in one link

Tags: php, html, methods, get

I have to use double time $_GET method in one link such as

```
<a href="*exercises.php?page=phpex?get=imdone#container*">
```

but it does not work. Any recommends?

Comment: <a href="exercises.php?page=phpex?get=imdone#container"> link

Comment: Yes! Show us some code that will help us understand your issue

Comment: please, edit your question, and put your code, so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only one `?` and seperate parameters with `&`

```
<a href="exercises.php?page=phpex&get=imdone#container">
```